# Comparing Color objects with ==

Tags: java

This example comes from [a code snippet posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761117/testing-if-colors-equal):

```
private double brickVal(Color c) {
    if (c == Color.RED) {
        return 10.0;
    } else if (c == Color.ORANGE) {
        return 8.0;
    } else if (c == Color.YELLOW) {
        return 6.0;
    } else if (c == Color.GREEN) {
        return 4.0;
    } else if (c == Color.CYAN) {
        return 2.0;
    } else if (c == Color.MAGENTA) {
        return 1.0;
    } else {
        return 1.0;
    }
}
```

Is the use of `==` here correct / best practice?

Comment: I wouldn't use both in the same function! In what context is this function being used?

Comment: This question [was mentioned on meta.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/can-we-revisit-did-i-write-that-code-myself)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not correct (and thus of course also not best practice). For example the condition `c == Color.GREEN` will be true if the method is called as `brickVal(Color.GREEN)`, but false if it is called as `brickVal(new Color(0, 255, 0))`. Since `Color.GREEN` is equal to `new Color(0, 255, 0)` this behavior is most likely unintentional (at least I can't imagine a scenario where you'd want for `brickVal(Color.GREEN)` to behave differently than `brickVal(new Color(0,255,0))`.

Of course if you know that the method will only ever be called using the "pre-made" colors and never using `new Color`, it will behave correctly. However I'd still advise against using `==`. I can see no good reason to not use `equals` and using `==` comes with the danger that someone might call `brickVal` with `new Color` anyway, not knowing that they're not supposed to.

Further given the fact that `brickVal` apparently is meant to be only called with some specific colors as arguments and it doesn't use any properties of the colors other than their identity, I think an enum might be more suitable here than using the `Color` class. This way you can use `switch` instead of `if ... else if ...` and don't have to worry about anybody passing in `new Color` as the argument.

---

As a somewhat unrelated note, I find it confusing that the `brickVal` variable is set in every case except if the argument is `RED` and in the else case. Obviously I don't know how and where the `brickVal` variable is going to be used, but this seems like a design smell to me. I also think it's a bad idea to have a variable with the same name as the method.

Comment: EDIT-ed question to get rid of the `brickval = ... ` and other cruft that detracted from my main question.

Answer (score 5):

My take on this is that it is bad practice.

In some circumstances, this code could be "correct" ... in the sense of being bug free as written.  Specifically, if the entire application was written to use only a predefined palette of `Color` objects ... and there was no way that it could introduce new `Color` objects into this calculation.

The problem is that this is potentially a global (application wide) invariant.  Any change to any class might potentially introduce new `Color` objects and violate the invariant.  In short the application is at best "fragile".

The other problem is that this dependency on an global invariant makes the class hard to reuse.

For these reasons, my take is that this approach is bad practice ... whether or not it is buggy in the context of the application.

Comment: I dont get it. The only problem I see is == vs 'equals', and maybe he should use a lookuptable instead of the repeated ifs.

Comment: @Martin - `==` versus equals is the point.

Answer (score 4):

The argument `c` is an instance of Color. When you use the `==` operator you are checking if the instances are pointing to the same object. In this case (and most cases that I encounter), you do not want to compare pointers, you want to compare values. After all, Color is a class that encapsulates a color value.
Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.Color;

class ColorTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Color c1 = Color.RED;
        Color c2 = new Color(255,0,0);
        System.out.println(c1 == c2); //false - not pointing to the same object
        System.out.println(c1.equals(c2)); //true - both are red
    }
}
```

This is why all java objects have a `equals()` method, which is inherited from the [Object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class: we don't care where it is physically stored in memory, we care about what it represents.

EDIT: So to answer the question "Is this good practice" I would say no it is not.

Comment: We actually do care a little about their memory location.  The first line of any good `equals()` function will always be `if (a == b) return true;`

Answer (score 3):

Not a good practice.

In the manner that is seems you want to use color - the thing that matters is the value. You want to know if the actual color is the same. It doesn't matter if it is 2 different objects that have the same values or the same object. And `==` checks if it is the same object.
what you want to use is `equals()` because `equals()` checks if the two colors have the same values.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked very well:

```
Color c1 = Color.WHITE;
Color c2 = new Color(255,255,255);

if(c1.getRGB() == c2.getRGB()) 

    System.out.println("true");

else

    System.out.println("false");

}
```

`getRGB` function returns an `int` value with the sum of Red Blue and Green, so we are comparing an `int` with `==`, and not an object with equals.

Comment: Could you explain why it's better than what the OP does? Specifically, do you feel all color comparisons should be done this way? Why so?

Comment: `(255,0,0)` and `(0,255,0)` and `(0,0,255)` are three distinctly different colors whose RGB values all sum up to the same number.